# The way to implement a configurable (at run-time) default style

Tags: design-patterns, c++, graph, configuration

I am coding a visualizer of graph algorithms. Each vertex of the graph has a style (color, size etc.). As long as the algorithm has done nothing to a vertex, that vertex has a *default style*. The default style needs to be configurable at run-time.

I came up with the following solution based on the singleton pattern, which seems a bit awkward to me (as indicated in the comment). Is there a better one?

```
struct Style {
    int color;
    // size etc. are skipped for brevity
};

// Changeable default style
struct DefaultStyle {
    static DefaultStyle &instance() {
        static DefaultStyle res;
        return res;
    }
    DefaultStyle() = default;
    DefaultStyle(DefaultStyle const &) = delete;
    void operator=(DefaultStyle const &) = delete;

    Style s{5}; 
        // didn't see a benefit in making it private, 
        // since I would need to provide get() and set() anyways. 
};

int main()
{
    auto &s = DefaultStyle::instance().s; 
       // this need to access the style indirectly (.s) seems awkward

    s.color = 10;

    std::cout << DefaultStyle::instance().s.color << std::endl;
       // the change is globally visible
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is not really specific to the graphs domain, so I think that the [graph] tag should be removed.

Comment: Sound like you want to use EventListeners..

Comment: Did you consider using [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) instead of making your own thing from scratch? And you need to define for which output (which graphics library - perhaps [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) or [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/), which file format - PDF, SVG, ....) you want to get the graphics.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am using `Cairo`, no file output, only drawing on screen.

Comment: I would consider being able to configure such things via program arguments

Comment: Your question seems to be how to manage the styles used by vertices. However, you don't show how you relate vertices to their style. Your example is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

**What's wrong here ?**

First, the purpose of a singleton is to ensure that a class has only one instance and to provide a global point of access to it:

- you indeed would benefit from a global point of access to the default style for initializing the style of new vertexes.
- but is there any need to have only one instance of it ?  E.g. couldn't you imagine your application having several windows with different diagrams, each having a different default style ?

Next, is the "default style" really a type/subclass ?  Isn't it rather a default value for the properties ?

- Imagine that you would have style classes such as `Thick`, `Dotted`, `Blinking`.  All these classes would have some common  properties like the `color` and `brush_style`.
- Now `Blinking` would need additional information about the `duration` of a blink.  In this case, it would not be sufficient to have a single default style class : you'd need as many default classes ad derived styles !

**How to address this design issue**

In my opinion, there are two main approaches:

- ***First option:*** If you use some [factory method](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html) to create your shapes and vertexes, just setup the factory when it is created with the default style (managed by value or by reference).
- ***Second option:*** As you want to use an object to create new ones by copying the [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) (i.e. default style), you could also think of a prototype design pattern

The two are not incompatible: if your styles could not be trivially copied (for instance, if they have some virtual functions), or if they could have different sizes, your first option would need the second to initialize the vertex style.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will be nicer to use.
The whole thing could be done by an assignable global variable, but I think it's still better to have explicit interface for it.

```
struct Style {
    int color;
    // size etc. are skipped for brevity
};

// Changeable default style
struct DefaultStyle {
    static const Style &get() {
        return style();
    }
    static void set(Style s) {
        style() = s;
    }
    DefaultStyle(DefaultStyle const &) = delete;
    void operator=(DefaultStyle const &) = delete;
    DefaultStyle() = delete;
private:
    static Style& style() {
        static Style s{5};
        return s;
    }
};

int main()
{
    DefaultStyle::set({10});

    std::cout << DefaultStyle::get().color << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I missed a very easy solution: use inheritance! After all, the default style is a style!

```
struct Style {
    int color;
    // width etc. are skipped for brevity
};

// Changeable default style
struct DefaultStyle: Style {
    static DefaultStyle &instance() {
        static DefaultStyle res;
        return res;
    }
    DefaultStyle(DefaultStyle const &) = delete;
    void operator=(DefaultStyle const &) = delete;
private:
    DefaultStyle() = default;
};

int main()
{
    auto &d = DefaultStyle::instance();
    d.color = 10;
    std::cout << DefaultStyle::instance().color << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 for the LSP violation: Style can be assigned to, DefaultStyle cannot.

Comment: @Sjoerd 1. I am bad with abbreviations. What does LSP stand for? 2. As far as I recall, the code compiles and runs. Why do you say (at least that's what I understood you were saying) that `d.color = 10` is illegal?

Comment: LSP = Liskov Substitution Principle. Look it up, it's an important principle for inheritance. It says that in any context where a `Style` can be used, it should be possible to replace it with a `DefaultStyle`. If that is not possible, (public) inheritance is not the right tool.

Comment: @Sjoerd Do you hold that `delete` should never be used in a derived class?